# How can I split a dataset and use cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

How can I split my dataset by using Greedy layer-Wise pre-training in Deep Learning Neural Networks?

As an example, if I have a dataset with 60000 samples:

- (? % for unsupervised pretraining)
- (? % for supervised fine tuning)
- (? %validation)
- (? % test)

How can I use cross-validation for hyperparameter optimization?